# How to find the mean within each polygon using raster and extract but excluding certain values

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a global raster file where I want to calculate a certain application rate of pesticides within each country. The raster file contains values -2 (which represents water), -1.5 (which represents missing values) and -1 (which represents a ban of a pesticide) which are not interesting and I need to exclude these and calculate the mean on all the other values.

```
# My raster file is called rast and has these properties

> rast
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 1681, 4306, 7238386  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -178.9167, 179.9167, -56.0425, 84.04084  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : APR_Corn_2.4.d_2015_L
```

So my idea was to simply replace all values < 0 in the raster file with NA and then combining it with a world map polygon using extract and mean. Here is the code:

```
# Load packages and polygon data
library(raster)
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

# Replace all the negative values with NA
rast.new = rast
rast.new[rast.new < 0] = NA

# Get the mean applcation rate (kg/ha) for each country
national_mean_apr_extr = raster::extract(rast.new, wrld_simpl, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This is what I get

```
> national_mean_apr_extr

               [,1]
  [1,]          NaN
  [2,] 4.422384e-02
  [3,] 8.333350e-03
  [4,] 3.638522e-02
  [5,] 1.683824e-02
  [6,] 3.001397e-04
  [7,]          NaN
  [8,] 2.022979e-01
  [9,] 4.490954e-02
 [10,]          NaN
 [11,]          NaN
 [12,]          NaN
 [13,]          NaN
 [14,] 1.050294e-02
 [15,] 6.948954e-02
```

So a lot of the values I get are NaN and I don't know why.

If I don't do the step of replacing all the negative numbers with NA it seems to work and I don't get any NaNs but the numbers are of course incorrect:

```
# Get the mean applcation rate (kg/ha) for each country
national_mean_apr_extr = raster::extract(rast, wrld_simpl, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
> national_mean_apr_extr
               [,1]
  [1,] -1.500000000
  [2,] -1.500888377
  [3,] -0.494337678
  [4,] -0.038511559
  [5,] -1.340424282
  [6,] -0.831025496
  [7,] -2.000000000
  [8,] -0.946029966
  [9,] -1.483374534
 [10,] -1.500000000
 [11,] -1.875000000
 [12,] -2.000000000
 [13,] -1.828125000
 [14,] -1.490271067
 [15,] -0.754035134
```

Any ideas why this is?

Edit: I have added a link to the raster file:
http://www.filedropper.com/aprcorn24-d2015l

Comment: Looks like the data has "NaN" in it as well. Check that the data is numeric, and also replace NaN with NA. NaN is used in e.g. Matlab.

Comment: But then it shouldn't work when I don't filter it, no? I checked now and it doesn't seem to have any NaN in the original raster file. I have also added a link to the raster file. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @SimonWoodward - R also has NaN. Try `0/0` or `Inf - Inf`

Comment: The link returns 404.

Comment: @Edward I have added another link with filedropper instead so not it shouldn't dissappear.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious reasons would be that all values for these countries are `NA`. For these countries you would get

```
mean(NA, na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] NaN
```

So all would seem to be working as intended.